# How to avoid duplicate values in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'table1' like this:

```
id    org_id  project_name project_id emp_id business_id         first_name  from_date 
3862    62      'Project1'    51       2          73             'Employee1' '2015-01-01'
3864    62      'Project2'    52       3          74             'Employee2' '2015-03-18'
3866    62      'Project2'    52       2          74             'Employee1' '2015-06-22'
```

I want to get unique employees.
Output should be like this:

```
id    org_id  project_name project_id emp_id business_id         first_name  from_date 
3862    62      'Project1'    51       2          73             'Employee1' '2015-01-01'
3864    62      'Project2'    52       3          74             'Employee2' '2015-03-18'
```

Any help!!

Comment: Do you want to get unique employees or avoid duplicates being entered?

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to do.

id    org_id  project_name project_id emp_id business_id

When you're creating your table put the UNIQUE constraint at the end of the values you want unique/not duplicated.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
id int NOT NULL,
org_id int NOT NULL,
project_name varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
project_id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
emp_id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
business_id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
from_date datetime NOT NULL,
)
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:** If you want entered information to be unique as well just:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

Then loop thought the values you recieved and check if the values project_name, project_id, emp_id, business_id or first_name are the same as one of the given values. Then the one of the values are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DISTINCT org_id,project_name,project_id,emp_id,business_id,first_name FROM table1
```